# Going up in smoke vs. going up in flames

Tags: meaning, idioms

The idioms **"to go up in smoke"** and **"to go up in flames"** are very similar. They both mean burning and getting destroyed by fire. But if we use them to talk about failure, aren't there any nuances to remember? Aren't there any shades of meaning that differ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Although these are both fire metaphors, they are not quite the same thing.

To "go up in smoke" means to disappear, dissipate, fail, or be destroyed as if by burning.  A similar idiom would be to be ["all for naught"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/All+For+Naught).

To "go up in flames" similarly means to burn, but usually more *spectacularly*, as if in a conflagration or other disaster. A similar idiom would be to "go down in flames" as in ["crash and burn"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crash+and+burn).

The first implies *wasted* or *futile* effort.  The second implies *spectacular failure*.

> My lifelong dream to become a doctor **went up in smoke** when I found out I would faint at the sight of blood.
>
> My long-term plan to become a doctor **went up in flames** when, as a college prank, my friends and I stole the yacht of what turned out to be the director of the medical school.

Because there is some overlap in these definitions, in many situations you can use either.

Comment: I’d love to see you revamp your second example. It leaves me wondering: isn’t there some way that one’s plans might go up in flames (instead of up in smoke) _without_ any literal fire?

Comment: @J.R. If something goes up in smoke, then it leaves no trace.  If something goes in up flames then it's leaves lasting damage.  An example for the second that doesn't involve literal flames would be   "My plan to become a famous doctor went up in flames when I killed the president"

Comment: @J.R.  yeah, me too.  I thought it was a bit hokey, but all the other options I came up with went to weird places.  Anyway, edited  :)

Comment: I guess the nuance is related to the expression "vanish in a puff of smoke" (i.e. to disappear completely).  This sense feeds "go up in smoke" as much as the fire metaphor does.

Comment: Capacitors can 'go up in smoke' without any signs of fire. The capacitors in PC PSUs is the case I have in mind where getting the voltage switch wrong can result in an impressive 'fwoop' sound and a cloud of smoke.

Comment: And to go _down_ in flames is even more spectacular.

Comment: @Andrew - Based on your subtle distinction, I'll tell you which ones went through my mind: _My lifelong dream to become a doctor went up in smoke after I failed my clinical exams for the third time in three years_ vs. _My lifelong dream to become a doctor went up in flames after I flunked four of my first five courses in premed._